# When Xdebug is enabled in a web request it won't step over and breaks at every single line and enters every function in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using Xdebug 3.

I'm able to step over normally in index.php at the beginning of the request until the request starts going through Laravel's complex routing and middleware system. After that, it breaks at every line and enters every function .

**What hasn't worked**

1. Setting nginx root directory to the actual folder instead of symlink
2. Disabling the resolve and force break options in the PhpStorm debug settings
3. Clearing PHPStorm cache and re-indexing
4. Removing any vendor libraries from "Excluded folders"
5. Removing the profile option from xdebug.mode in xdebug.ini
6. Disabling xdebug.start_upon_error
7. Disabling Clockwork

Debugger validation
[image]

Here's my xdebug.ini:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
; https://xdebug.org/docs/install
; xdebug.mode = profile
; Uncomment if you want to profile with clockwork xdebug.mode=debug,profile
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port = 9003
; I think it might have problems writing to project folders in WSL so use /var/log
xdebug.log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
```

Here are the PhpStorm Debug Settings:

[image: PhpStorm Debug Settings]

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that I had overridden a Laravel library file with a custom version using the "files" section in composer.json.  Apparently, Xdebug/PHPStorm got confused by the path mappings after that file was called.

I did the override long ago and it was never a problem for Xdebug before. I haven't updated PHPStorm, Xdebug or changed anything recently so I'm still not sure why it suddenly started occurring.